# Laravel 5.5 - Modify output of ::all

Tags: laravel

I am getting all 'fruits' in a Laravel 5.5 controller like this...

```
    $fruits = Fruit::all();

    return Response::json(array(
        'error' => false,
        'fruits' => $fruits,
    ));
```

This is working but is there a way to specify exactly what data comes out like when you are querying just one item like this...

```
$fruit = Fruit::find($id);

$fruit_array = array();

$fruit_array['id'] = $fruit->id;
$fruit_array['title'] = $fruit->title;
$fruit_array['colour'] = $fruit->colour;

return Response::json(array(
    'error' => false,
    'fruits' => $fruits,
));
```

Anyone have an example I can see?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Query Builder`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#selects) like this:

```
$result = DB::table('fruits')
            ->select('id', 'title', 'colour')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Laravel Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources). Basically you create a class that extends the `Resource` class and just call `toArray($request)`.

So you can create a `FruitResource.php` class that looks like:

```
class FruitResource extends \Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource 
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this-id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'colour' => $this->colour,
            // anything you want, including more resources or relationships to fruits
            'user' => $this->user
        ];
    }
}
```

Then you call the `FruitResource.php` like this:

```
return Response::json(array(
    'error' => false,
    'fruits' => FruitResource::collection($fruits),
));
```

The reason I like this way of doing it is that when you need a ton of customization in your responses, you can organize them nicely in a new Resource.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$visible` protected property in your model. `$visible` is an array that holds key/value pairs you want to show up in your JSON outputs.

> Alternatively, you may use the visible property to define a white-list
>   of attributes that should be included in your model's array and JSON
>   representation. All other attributes will be hidden when the model is
>   converted to an array or JSON.

[JSON Visibility](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json)

So in your model add a property to the class:

```
protected $visible = [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'title' => $this->title,
    'colour' => $this->colour,
];
```

Additionally if you want to add more info that doesn't exist in the columns, you can use `$appends`. [Appends Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)

If you have an accessor called `getIsFancyAttribute()` you can use:

`protected $appends = [ 'is_fancy' => $this->is_fancy '];`

Answer (score 1):

You can `pass` additional array of attribute in `find()` method to specify what `column` data you want to `fetch`:

```
Fruit::find(1, ['id', 'title']);
```